# How to find out why explorer crashed on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10

Since I started my PC this morning my taskbar keeps continously restarting about every minute. Where can I look for hints on the cause of these crashes?

Comment: `Event Viewer` would be a start.

Comment: capture a crash dump: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ  and share it.

Comment: Windows 10 RTM?

Comment: have you captured the crash dump?

Answer (score 0):

The EventViewer showed me exactly what I needed. The crashes were caused by the .stl explorer rendering plugin of Autodesk Moldflow.